# Text Rebus Extreme!

Tags: rebus

I made these all myself. No images, but hopefully still fun:

---

**shbandip**

---

**all**
**__**
**map**

---

**pantsants**

---

**rsnug=bugug**

---

**wits'<-**

---

**Requirements:**

- You must answer each one
- You must explain how each one works
- Both of the above must be correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1.

> abandon ship (a "band" in "ship")

2.

> all over the map (the word "all" is over the word "map")

3.

> ants in your pants ("ants" is inside "pants")

4.

> snug as a bug in a rug (snug=bug means "snug is a bug", which sounds like "snug as a bug", and it's inside the word "rug")

5.

> at wits' end (arrow pointing to the end of wits')

Comment: Be honest with me, were they hard? Did you enjoy them?

Comment: @warspyking They weren't difficult, but sure they were a nice diversion from work. ;)

Comment: @pace Glad you liked them :D

Comment: Perhaps you'll enjoy http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9647/text-rebus-extreme-2