# Text Rebus Extreme! 2!

Tags: rebus

The second rebus question in the series.

---

**here**
**____**
**bored**

---

**bets**
**_**

---

**all4114**

---

**knightleg**

---

**A**
\
**C**

---

**<3 <-**

---

**Requirements:**

- You must answer each one
- You must explain how each one works
- Both of the above must be correct

**Hint #1:** They are all cliches.

Comment: We can't give partial answers, can we?

Comment: @TheDragonista Why not? It's often been done before.

Comment: @randal'thor I was confused because the question clearly states "You must answer each one"

Comment: @The Dragonista That is only there for it be be marked correct and accepted :)

Comment: Gotcha! Now what troubles me is why is such an excellent collection of rebuses getting down voted??!!!?

Comment: @The Dragonista Well, that's the community's reasons. I'd love to improve the question, but nobody specified the problem.

Comment: @TheDragonista (I didn't DV, but) how can you tell it's an excellent collection of rebuses until the answers are published? Of the 3 solved so far, one was obvious and the other two were wild stabs in the dark not really expecting to be correct.

Comment: @rand al'thor well actually knightleg had an alternative answer (arm and a leg) because a knights leg is ARMoured. But knightly works.

Answer (score 3):

```
here
__
bored
```

> **Above-board**

```
bets
_
```

> **All bets are off**

```
all4114
```

> **All for one and one for all**

```
knightleg
```

> **Nightly**

```
A
\
C
```

> **To be or not to be** (between A and C there is B -> Be but you replace it by )

```
<3 <-
```

> **After my own heart** (<3 = heart and <- point after it)

Comment: Last 2 are incorrect.

Comment: @warspyking i updated the last one, it is still incorrect ?

Comment: It is correct. ${}$

Comment: only one left ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
here
__
bored
```

> **Above-board**

```
bets
_
```

> **bets are off**

```
all4114
```

> **All for one and one for all**

```
knightleg
```

> **Nightly**

```
A
\
C
```

> **Across the sea** (A - and then \ can be used to *cross something out* and then the sea (pronunciation of C)

```
<3 <-
```

> **After my own heart**

Answer (score 1):

Some of these answers are a bit jokey, but then warspyking is jokey, so who knows - they might be right!

**here**
**____**
**bored**

> **Above-board** (the word 'here' is only to indicate the point of focus).

**bets**
**_**

> **All bets are off.** (bets is coming "off" the line)

**all4114**

> **All for one and one for all.** (easiest one)

**knightleg**

> **Nightly** (as in happening every night; the G silent as in some Gaelic words)

**A**
\
**C**

> **see after a slope** (wild guessing here, but so were a couple of the ones I got right)

**<3 <-**

> **After one's own heart** (arrow pointing after heart) - thanks to Pierre-Arthur Ferraro for this one!

Comment: bets, all4114, knightleg are correct.

Comment: @warspyking Really? Knightleg was more like a joke, and bets just a guess! Can you edit my answer to explain the bets one better?

Comment: Still no. ${}{}$

Comment: Good, the first one is correct. (Above-board)

Comment: Quite alright. Now you just need to figure out the last 2. Remember, they are cliches!

Comment: @warspyking Any chance of a hint for the last one?

Comment: maybe after a few more tries. *Yes, I just encoded your hint in a message :D*

Comment: @warspyking I've updated the last one again - any joy? Also, any chance of a hint on the penultimate one?

Comment: This guy has the last one right: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/9839/2383

Comment: @warspyking Edited again.

Comment: Someone just undid their upvote. Did my answer get worse with my last edit, or what?

Comment: Still not right. Hint: It's bent up a bit.

Comment: @warspyking I think I have a too-dirty mind; your hint is just making me think of obscene interpretations :-p

Answer (score 0):

here

---

bored

> here I lay, bored!

bets
_

> bets are high

all4114

> all for one , one for all

knightleg
 I don't know the answer for this one

A
\
C

> Alternating current, the slash alternates between left and right

<3 <-

> Love struck

Comment: all4114 is correct here.